# free is leading to memory corruption

Tags: c, arrays, memory-corruption

Friends,
I am trying to free memory from pointer array as:

```
const gchar *strings[21];
strings[0]  = malloc(strAuth)
strings[0]  = strAuth
....
....
    int j=0;
    while(j < 20){
      if (strlen(strings[j]) != 0) {
    g_free((char*)strings[j]);
    g_print("Cleaned:%d\n",j);
      }
      j++;
      g_print("%d",j);
    }
//g_free((char*)strings);
```

j prints upto 20 and then gives

```
$ ./mkbib 
Cleaned:0
1Cleaned:1
2Cleaned:2
34Cleaned:4
56789101112Cleaned:12
1314151617181920*** glibc detected *** ./mkbib: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000000a14e10 ***
```

Any explanation (to a C-novice)?

**EDIT 1** Sorry for the stupid info, I was avoiding what strAuth is because that involves gtk library(I have bad experience about asking specific library dependent question in clc). So the **real** code looks:

```
 strings[0]  = g_malloc(strlen(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(e->entry1))));
 strings[0]  = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(e->entry1));
```

where `gtk_entry_get_text` is of type  `const gchar *`
Possibly I have wasted you time with initial post. Please help.

**EDIT 2**

```
const gchar *strings[21]; 
strings[0] = g_malloc(strlen(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(e->entry1)))); 
strings[0] =g_strdup(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(e->entry1))); 
........
int i=2; 
    while (i < 21) {
      if (strlen(strings[i]) != 0) {
    g_string_append_printf(tstring, ",\n\t%s=\"%s\"",
        keyword[i], strings[i]);
      g_free((char*)strings[i]);
      strings[i]=NULL;
      g_print("Cleaned:%d\n",i);
      } 
      i++;
 }
```

Comment: What is strAuth and why are you passing it to malloc (which takes a size_t )?

Comment: I have managed to (probably) fixed it using. Kindly have a look at edit 2. 
Since, I have not found any way to check if strings are really deallocated, please comment if this looks better.

Comment: @Rudra: Your code in EDIT2 still suffers from memory leaks (part "secondly" in my answer). You don't need `g_malloc` if you do `g_strdup`. Also, what is `tstring` and how is it declared/allocated?

Comment: Finally, did you initialize *all* of `strings` before the cycle?

Comment: @AndreyT
`GString *tstring = g_string_new ("");` where GString is defined as 
[link](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Strings.html#g-string-new).

Comment: @AndreyT,

I have just done that 
`const gchar *strings[21]=""; `

Anything else should I look at?

Comment: @Rudra: `const gchar *strings[21]=""` will not even compile. You have to pay more attention to what you post. It is impossible to figure out what's wrong with your code, if one cannot be sure that what you post has any relation to your actual code.

Comment: sorry for that, as I am having problem with copy-paste from my code.
It is actually `const gchar *strings[21]={""}`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this

```
strings[0]  = malloc(strAuth)
strings[0]  = strAuth;
```

is defintely broken. What is the type of `strAuth`? How did you manage to use `strAuth` as argument of `malloc` (i.e. size) and then immediately as the right-hand size of assignment? `malloc`s argument must be an integer, while `strings[0]` has pointer type. Aside from being completely self-contradictory, this sort of usage will trigger diagnostic messages from the compiler. Did you just ignore those messages?

If `strAuth` is a string and if you are trying to allocate memory for a copy of `strAuth`, then the typical memory allocation idiom would be

```
strings[0] = malloc(strlen(strAuth) + 1);
```

Secondly, why are you even attempting to assign anything to `strings[0]` after `malloc`? The pointer in `strings[0]` is your only connection to the freshly allocated memory, which you should cherish and preserve by all means. Instead you immediately clobber that pointer by assigning a new value to `strings[0]`, turning the memory you just allocated into a memory leak.

Again, if you are trying to create a copy of `strAuth` in `strings[0]`, then the typical idiom would be

```
strings[0] = malloc(strlen(strAuth) + 1);
strcpy(strings[0], strAuth);
```

(of course, in real code one should always remember to check whether `malloc` succeeded or not).

On many platforms a non-standard `strdup` function is available, which wraps exactly the above allocate-and-copy functionality, meaning that the above two lines can be replaced with simple

```
strings[0] = strdup(strAuth);
```

And finally, thirdly, what is `g_free`? Are you sure it is applicable to memory allocated by standard `malloc` (as opposed to, say, `g_malloc`). And even if it happens to be applicable, it is still not a good idea to mix APIs like that. If you want to allocate memory by standard `malloc` (or `strdup`), then it is a good idea to stick to standard `free` for freeing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
strings[0]  = malloc(strAuth)
strings[0]  = strAuth
```

After allocating memory for `strings[0]`, you overwrite the returned pointer with `strAuth`, which I don't know what it is, but probably a string which was not allocated using `malloc()` (or one of its relatives like `realloc()`). And you can't free such an object.

(and anyways: if `strAuth` is a string, shouldn't you allocate enough space for its **length** (plus one for the terminating NUL byte) instead? `malloc(strAuth)` seems nonsensical to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's add some comments to help you out:

```
const gchar *strings[21];     // allocate an array of 21 pointers to gchar constants
strings[0]  = malloc(strAuth) // assign some memory (strAuth number of bytes) to the
                              //   first pointer
strings[0]  = strAuth         // reassign the first pointer the value of strAuth
```

When you do the assignment of `strAuth` to `strings[0]` you're overwriting what was malloc'd there in the first place. So if `strAuth` is some string literal or something not malloc'd then a call to free would indeed fail. You can only free what has been dynamically allocated.

So you need to decide if you want to stick pointers to constant strings in your array (and don’t malloc or free) or if you want to malloc/free and then copy your strings into the array.

Note you're calling [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) in conjunction with [`g_free()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-free) [that's not a good idea.](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2000-July/msg00002.html) [`g_malloc()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-malloc) and [`g_free()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-free) are more than just wrappers around [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) and [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and so you should use them as such... pseudo-code explanation:

```
if 
    g_malloc(strings[x]) 
  then 
    g_free(strings[x])
else if 
    strings[x] = malloc(y) 
  then 
    free(strings[x])
```